# nginx file rewrite using multi-level regular expression

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm developing a file server using nginx. For accessing the server file I need to append a string after each directory.

**Example:**
My URL is

```
http://desk09/1.2/junior/kal12/pnr.doc
```

I need to change this to local file named

```
../junior@1.2/kal12@1.2/pnr.doc
```

Can I do it using nginx configuration file alone something like below:

```
location ~ "^/([1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}/(.*)" {
    root /usr/home/fs/......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change my answer to make it work recursive:

First throw version number from begining and add this to first directory

```
location ~ "^/([0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1})/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*\.doc)$" {
    rewrite     .*  /$2@$1/$3;
}
```

So now url:

```
/1.2/junior/many_sub_dir_here/test.doc    ->   /junior@1.2/many_sub_dir_here/test.doc
```

Now `location` directive belove will work as recursive location (so You have mark nginx to allow recursive location invocation):

```
location ~ "^(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+@)([0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1})/(([a-zA-Z0-9]+@[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}/)*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*\.doc)$" {
    rewrite .* /$1$2/$3$5@$2/$6;        
}
```

For your url it will work as follow

```
/junior@1.2/x1/x2/x3/test.doc           -->   /junior@1.2/x1@1.2/x2/x3/test.doc
  $1 = /junior@
  $2 = 1.2
  $3 = 
  $4 = 
  $5 = x1
  $6 = x2/x3/test.doc

/junior@1.2/x1@1.2/x2/x3/test.doc       -->   /junior@1.2/x1@1.2/x2@1.2/x3/test.doc
  $1 = /junior
  $2 = 1.2
  $3 = x1@1.2/
  $4 = x1@1.2/
  $5 = x2
  $6 = x3/text.doc

/junior@1.2/x1@1.2/x2@1.2/x3/test.doc   -->   /junior@1.2/x1@1.2/x2@1.2/x3@1.2/test.doc
  $1 = /junior@
  $2 = 1.2
  $3 = x1@1.2/x2@1.2/
  $4 = x2@1.2/
  $5 = x3
  $6 = test.doc
```

This last url won't anymore matches regex in above `location` block so here we comes with final location block like this:

```
location ~ ".*(@[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1})/[^@/]+\.doc$" {
    root root /usr/home/fs;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.
But the name of file and directory specified is just an example. The actual issue is I cannot predict the depth of sub-directories.
As another example the URL and file can be like `http://desk09/1.2/junior/test.doc` and `../junior@1.2/test.doc`
or
`http://desk09/1.2/junior/x1/x2/x3/test.doc` and `../junior@1.2/x1@1.2/x2@1.2/x3@1.2/test.doc`

Comment: Oh, I see... I will rethink it if anything comes into my mind I will update answer :)